# Correctly posting data with authentication in JavaScript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, medium.com-publishing-api

I am writing an application through Electron for a simple text editor that posts drafts to Medium.com. They provide an API and the documentation for it, but my knowledge in jQuery and JavaScript is still a little limited. Essentially, I'm using AJAX to post the data to Medium, but receiving a 400 error. I'm sure it's something really dumb and simple, but I can't figure it out, so here's the code I've written to post the data:

```
$('.save_draft').click(function(){
    
    var accessToken = 'xxxxx';
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.medium.com/v1/users/" + user.id + "/posts",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication", accessToken)
        },
        data: {
            "title": "Liverpool FC",
            "contentFormat": "html",
            "content": "<h1>Liverpool FC</h1><p>You’ll never walk alone.</p>",
            "canonicalUrl": "http://jamietalbot.com/posts/liverpool-fc",
            "tags": ["football", "sport", "Liverpool"],
            "publishStatus": "draft",
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Now I'm providing the `accessToken`, I've just 'xxxxx'd it for posting. user.id is received at the start, I can confirm that it's coming through correctly. As for the documentation provided, you can see it here: https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs#33-posts but essentially it's asking for this:

```
POST /v1/users/5303d74c64f66366f00cb9b2a94f3251bf5/posts HTTP/1.1
Host: api.medium.com
Authorization: Bearer 181d415f34379af07b2c11d144dfbe35d
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Accept-Charset: utf-8
{
 "title": "Liverpool FC",
 "contentFormat": "html",
 "content": "<h1>Liverpool FC</h1><p>You’ll never walk alone.</p>",
 "canonicalUrl": "http://jamietalbot.com/posts/liverpool-fc",
 "tags": ["football", "sport", "Liverpool"],
 "publishStatus": "public"
}
```

The updated code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://api.medium.com:443/v1/users/" + user.data.id + "/posts",
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "title": "Liverpool FC",
            "contentFormat": "html",
            "content": "<h1>Liverpool FC</h1><p>You’ll never walk alone.</p>",
            "canonicalUrl": "http://jamietalbot.com/posts/liverpool-fc",
            "tags": ["football", "sport", "Liverpool"],
            "publishStatus": "draft",
        }),
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you check what the 400 error response  is? Usually it explains what is missing

Answer (score 1):

For setting headers you shoud use the `header` property when sending ajax request.

```
// Request with a header property
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }
});
```

Also you shoud `stringify` your data before send:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
        "title": "Liverpool FC",
        "contentFormat": "html",
        "content": "<h1>Liverpool FC</h1><p>You’ll never walk alone.</p>",
        "canonicalUrl": "http://jamietalbot.com/posts/liverpool-fc",
        "tags": ["football", "sport", "Liverpool"],
        "publishStatus": "draft",
    }),
```

But it should be another problem with your request as well. 400 error means that you havent send a required field to the service

Comment: Thats great thanks, i've updated it that now and it's stopped giving me the 400 error, now a 401, authentication error with the wrong host? `code: -1 message : " is not an allowed domain. Our host is (api.medium.com:443, /v1/users/myUserIdHere/posts)"`. So i've added my updated code to the original post so you can see what i'm doing, but it's as instructed by the documentation.

Comment: 401 means that the accessToken is invalid. Are u sure you are sending a valid token?

Comment: there must be something wrong, please read the documentation, in general this is the way to do an ajax request as my answer suggests.
Also try to change the url to `"https://api.medium.com/v1/users/" + user.data.id + "/posts"`

Comment: I had that url originally, only added the port because it was the url given in the 401 error. So not to sure to be honest. I'll find it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar problem (401 'is not an allowed domain' response on POST) and resolved the issue by including an additional header with the request:

```
Origin: https://api.medium.com
```